# Accessing devices behind routers without port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

Routers obviously are capable of communication between a particular computer in the local network and the internet.

Now, if I happened to know the local ip address of a device, and also the public IP address of it's router, how can I communicate with that device from the internet without having to use port forwarding.

The reason why I ask this is because I'm constantly on the move and I try hosting a server on my laptop with my phone's carrier data, but they do not allow port forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can necessarily "communicate" with a device behind a blocked port.
The only thing I've seen that comes remotely close is using aireplay-ng, a tool part of the aircrack-ng suite, to deauthenticate a specific device from a wireless AP based on the MAC address, though that's quite different versus what you're trying to.